# PDO Insert with Select Statement Error / Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Doing the query manually in PHPMyAdmin

```
INSERT INTO productimages (ImageURL, productID)
VALUES('http://test.jpg', (SELECT id
                     FROM products 
                    WHERE products.MPN = 'test'));
```

Works just fine.

But trying to use PDO...

```
try {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO productimages (ImageURL, productID)
VALUES(':image_url', (SELECT id
                     FROM products 
                    WHERE products.MPN = ':mpn'));";
    $data = [
    'image_url' => $image_url,
    'mpn' => $mpn
];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo '<h2 style="color:red;">' . $e->getMessage() . '</h2>';
    }
```

I am always getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

How do I properly form this INSERT query to perform with PDO?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you.  That worked.  Once I added backtick's (`) to the tables and columns, it performs correctly.

Comment: You're welcome Brian; always glad to see that the duplicate(s) helped in solving it yourself, *cheers* :)